# Show footnotes on each page for footnote in ltablex

Tags: footnotes, ltablex

For footnotes in a long `ltablex`, the default configuration gather all the footnotes in the last page in the table. Is that possible to show footnote in their corresponding page, instead of having it all in the end?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\lipsum[1]&\lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&\lipsum[4]\\\hline
\lipsum[5]\footnote{Footnote 1}&\lipsum[6]\\\hline
\lipsum[7]&\lipsum[8]\footnote{Footnote 2}\\\hline
\lipsum[9]&\lipsum[10]\footnote{Footnote 3}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone had the same problem, here's a solution, although I don't know why it works.
In your preamble, add`\usepackage{hyperref}` right after `\usepackage{ltablex}` so your preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\lipsum[1]&\lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&\lipsum[4]\\\hline
\lipsum[5]\footnote{Footnote 1}&\lipsum[6]\\\hline
\lipsum[7]&\lipsum[8]\footnote{Footnote 2}\\\hline
\lipsum[9]&\lipsum[10]\footnote{Footnote 3}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The page footnotes will then appear on each page where the footnoting is made, rather than appearing all where the table finishes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but as this question still popped up when I was looking for a solution, I'm hoping this will benefit somebody else. It's not an answer, but more of a workaround.

What you do, is split the table up in multiple tables and resize them so that below each table, there is enough room for the footnotes from that particular section of the table. If you specify `addtocounter{table}{-1}` between each of the tables, you can use `\caption[]{Original caption -- continued}` without the counter incrementing. Using the empty pair of square brackets hides this (second, third, ..., nth) table from the list of tables, while still displaying it above the table.

As my pages were on separate landscape-pages and I was only struggling with this when finishing my report, the size and position of the table were more or less fixed -- so the manual adjustments were no problem.